# Does converting between byte[] and MemoryStream cause overhead?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to know if there's overhead when converting between byte arrays and Streams (specifically MemoryStreams when using `MemoryStream.ToArray()` and `MemoryStream(byte[])`. I assume it's temporary doubling memory usage.

For example, I read as a stream, convert to bytes, and then convert to stream again.
But getting rid of that byte conversion will require a bit of a rewrite. I don't want to waste time rewriting it if it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: You could check the source code: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/memorystream.cs

Comment: Thanks for that. Never thought of doing that. If I'm right to believe that in C#, arrays are passed by reference, then MemoryStream(byte[]) doesn't really provide any overhead. But MemoryStream.ToArray() does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, yes.. you are correct in assuming that `ToArray` duplicates the memory in the stream.

If you want do not want to do this (for efficiency reasons), you could modify the bytes directly in the stream. Take a look at this:

```
// create some bytes: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7...
var originalBytes = Enumerable.Range(0, 256).Select(Convert.ToByte).ToArray();

using(var ms = new MemoryStream(originalBytes)) // ms is referencing bytes array, not duplicating it
{
    // var duplicatedBytes = ms.ToArray(); // copy of originalBytes array

    // If you don't want to duplicate the bytes but want to
    // modify the buffer directly, you could do this:

    var bufRef = ms.GetBuffer();

    for(var i = 0; i < bufRef.Length; ++i)
    {
        bufRef[i] = Convert.ToByte(bufRef[i] ^ 0x55);
    }

    // or this:
    /*
    ms.TryGetBuffer(out var buf);
    for (var i = 0; i < buf.Count; ++i)
    {
        buf[i] = Convert.ToByte(buf[i] ^ 0x55);
    }*/

    // or this:
    /*
    for (var i = 0; i < ms.Length; ++i)
    {
        ms.Position = i;
        var b = ms.ReadByte();

        ms.Position = i;
        ms.WriteByte(Convert.ToByte(b ^ 0x55));
    }*/
}

// originalBytes will now be 85,84,87,86...
```

### ETA:

Edited to add in Blindy's examples. Thanks! -- Totally forgot about `GetBuffer` and had no idea about `TryGetBuffer`

Answer (score 2):

> Does `MemoryStream(byte[])` cause a memory copy?

No, it's a non-resizable stream, and as such no copy is necessary.

> Does `MemoryStream.ToArray()` cause a memory copy?

Yes, by design it creates a copy of the active buffer. This is to cover the resizable case, where the buffer used by the stream is not the same buffer that was initially provided due to reallocations to increase/decrease its size.

> Alternatives to `MemoryStream.ToArray()` that don't cause memory copy?

Sure, you have `MemoryStream.TryGetBuffer (out ArraySegment<byte> buffer)`, which returns a segment pointing to the internal buffer, whether or not it's resizable. If it's non-resizable, it's a segment into your original array.

You also have `MemoryStream.GetBuffer`, which returns the entire internal buffer. Note that in the resizable case, this will be a lot larger than the actual used stream space, and you'll have to adjust for that in code.

And lastly, you don't always actually need a byte array, sometimes you just need to write it to another stream (a file, a socket, a compression stream, an Http response, etc). For this, you have `MemoryStream.CopyTo[Async]`, which also doesn't perform any copies.