# How does one get the MAUI.Graphics.IImage object from image picked from mediaPicker?

Tags: c#, xamarin, graphics, stream, maui

I have been trying to get `Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.IImage` object from the image I picked using `Microsoft.Maui.Media.MediaPicker`.

I tried to use

```
var file = await MediaPicker.PickPhotoAsync(new MediaPickerOptions
            {
                Title = "Pick a photo"
            });

var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
var filestream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
await filestream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);

byte[] byteArray = memoryStream.ToArray();
Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.IImage image;
Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.IImage newImage;
image = Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Platform.PlatformImage.FromStream(memoryStream);

if (image != null)
{
    newImage = image.Resize(720, 1280, ResizeMode.Stretch, true);
}
```

Now, the execution throws the error "Object not set to an instance of the object".
I debugged and saw that although the photo was being picked and was being loaded into the Memory Stream, the 'image' variable does not store the data after being assigned the value in the line:

```
image = Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Platform.PlatformImage.FromStream(memoryStream);
```

The condition:

```
if (image != null)
```

returns true, but using the resize function throws the "Object not set to an instance of the object" error.

Comment: As an aside, you should properly close the `filestream` after you are done with it via an `await using` statement: `await using var filestream = await file.OpenReadAsync();`.  Also, you create the `byteArray` without using it.  MemorySream.ToArray() [duplicates the array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63638249) so I recommend not doing that.

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to share the full `ToString()` output of the exception, including the exception type, message, **traceback** and inner exception(s) if any?  It's possible the *Object not set to an instance of the object* exception is being thrown from inside `image.Resize()`.

Comment: Also,what platform are you running on? It might help narrow down the problem if you would [edit] your question to [tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/tagging) it with your platform.  According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/graphics/images?view=net-maui-7.0), *The `PlatformImage` type isn't supported on Windows.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for replies. For now, I have used the platforms specific code to use Android.Graphics.Bitmap class and iOS UIImage class respectively for each platform. This enables me to store the image in platform specific class objects instead of finding a multi platform class to store the image and resize it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use your byte array ?

Try something like this :

```
Stream stream = await photo.OpenReadAsync();

stream.Position = 0;
byte[] byteArray;

using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(stream))
{
   byteArray = br.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
}
```

And so, use `LoadImageFromBytes`  [Here the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/graphics/images?view=net-maui-7.0#load-an-image)

Hope it helps.